# How to add an <ALL> option to an access ComboBox

Tags: sql, database, vba

Okay, so after spending a few hours on this, and following numerous online tutorials, I still cant get this ..working..

Basically,I have the ComboBox displaying an `<ALL>` option, but for the report, it doesn't actually return anything, it's just simply there for aesthetics at the moment. How do I get it to return data? There are 3 combo box's that need to be filled out, one being Treatment Type, another for Treatment Date (Both of which will frequently use (ALL) ), and Birth Month, which will always be a specific month.

The query for the Treatment Type ComboBox is as follows:

```
Select "(All Records)" 
FROM Treatment
UNION Select Treatment.Treatment
From Treatment;
```

The query for the Treatment Date ComboBox is as follows:

```
Select 0, "(All Records)"  
FROM Events 
UNION 
Select  Events.DatefieldID, Events.Datefields
From Events;
```

Comment: I think the solution will be in how you use the value returned from your combo box in your report... what does that code / query look like?

Comment: What do you mean? I was given the database to fix it up, because some other dev has messed it up.. so now i have to try and figure our what he's done aswell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<All>` isn't a special value that's understood by Sql...

if you're checking in your other query that `where treatmentType = [Value From Combo Box]`... and the value in the combo box is "`<All>`".. then no rows will match that condition, and nothing will be returned.

Instead, you'll need to adjust your logic to handle the `<All>` value differently...

`where treatmentType = [Value From Combo Box] OR [Value From Combo Box] = "<All>"`

Comment: Im still really rusty at SQL since I last done it mid last year, so i should put the WHERE statement after the Union?

Comment: This `where` statement wouldn't go in any of the code that you've posted... instead, it would go into the code / sql query that is using the value selected in the combobox.

Comment: Yeah see, that's my problem, If im understanding you right, there's a button that brings up the report based on what the input of the combo box, however, the original developer wrote VBA for this button - im a java guy, not VB :/

Comment: Glad you replaced the original writer ;)

Comment: Can anyone further help me?

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to Michaels solution, you could use use the SQL wildcard `%` (which is `*` in Access) to match all records.
Row Source query for the combobox:

```
Select "*" 
FROM Treatment
UNION Select Treatment.Treatment
From Treatment;
```

And `Like [Forms]![FormName]![ComboboxName]` as criteria for the field `Treatment` in the result query.
You will notice that empty fields are still not matched. This can be archived by filtering for the field `Nz([Treatment],0)` instead (makes Access return `0`, which is matched by `*`, instead of `NULL`, which is not).

This kept my result query's SQL code including a lot of joints leaner.